# android DialogInterface force closing

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a button that when clicked I want to load a layout. The layout has clickable icons of Dice. I have the button declared but when clicked it won't load the layout.

If it does load the layout and a dice is clicked it force closes because the new box that loads with the dice number cant take the place of the dice layout. I am not sure exactly if what I am saying is making sense and my code could be wrong.

Basically I want, when the button is clicked I want my xml of dice to load and the images clickable and when clicked to return a value in the range of the given dice.

```
 private CustomPopupWindow mDiceMenu;

 protected void showDicePopUp(View paramView) {
    this.mDiceMenu = new CustomPopupWindow(paramView);
    View.OnClickListener local3 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
            MainActivity.this.onDiceDialogClick(paramAnonymousView);
        }
    };
    this.mDiceMenu.setContentView(R.layout.dice);
    this.mDiceMenu.findViewById(R.id.dice_4).setOnClickListener(local3);
    this.mDiceMenu.findViewById(R.id.dice_6).setOnClickListener(local3);
    this.mDiceMenu.findViewById(R.id.dice_10).setOnClickListener(local3);
    this.mDiceMenu.findViewById(R.id.dice_20).setOnClickListener(local3);
    this.mDiceMenu.findViewById(R.id.planeswalker_dice).setOnClickListener(
            local3);
    this.mDiceMenu.findViewById(R.id.coin).setOnClickListener(local3);
}

   private void displayDiceResult(int paramInt) {
    int i = 1 + this.mRandom.nextInt(paramInt);
    this.mDiceMenu.dismiss();
    TextView localTextView = new TextView(this);
    localTextView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    localTextView.setTextSize(52.0F);
    localTextView.setTextColor(-16777216);
    localTextView.setGravity(17);
    localTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.planeswalker_dice);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.dice_roll) + "(D" + paramInt +")")
            .setView(localTextView)
            .setPositiveButton(getText(17039370),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt) {
                                  paramAnonymousDialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
 }
```